# In Java, Azure applicationinsights starter dependency not compatible with spring boot 3.x.x

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, azure-application-insights, appinsights

I wanted to integrate application insights into my spring boot application**(v3.x.x)** and for that I have used below dependency in my build.gradle.

`implementation 'com.microsoft.azure:applicationinsights-spring-boot-starter:2.6.4'`

In my controller, I have injected TelemetryClient bean like:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    TelemetryClient telemetryClient;

    @GetMapping("/greetings")
    public String greetings() {
        // send event
        telemetryClient.trackEvent("URI /greeting is triggered");

        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

And, To connect to my azure app insights I used :

```
APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING=somevalue
```

as Environment variable while running application in IntellijIdea.

Now, Application runs and complains about:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field telemetryClient in com.example.demo.app.insights.UserController required a bean of type 'com.microsoft.applicationinsights.TelemetryClient' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.microsoft.applicationinsights.TelemetryClient' in your configuration.
```

But, as soon as I downgrade my spring boot version from 3.x.x to 2.7.11, it works fine with the same piece of code and starts the application.

Has anyone else also has experienced similar issue of appinsights with spring boot on 3.x.x ? or Any idea of its fix in latest spring boot version ?

Comment: Hello, the dependency was the old way to use app insight; i suggest you to use the agent instead https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-standalone-upgrade-from-2x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been resolved in https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Java/issues/3016

Below dependency is compatible with spring boot 3.x:

```
api('com.microsoft.azure:applicationinsights-core:3.4.11');
// api 'com.microsoft.azure:applicationinsights-spring-boot-starter:2.6.4' // not compatible with spring 3.x
```

After that TelemetryClient Bean can be injected like:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class UserController {

    private final TelemetryClient telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient();

    @GetMapping("/greetings")
    public String greetings() {
        // send event
        telemetryClient.trackEvent("URI /greeting is triggered");

        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*I have tried with the same dependency with spring boot 3.x.x version, and I got the same error:*

[image]

***Result:***

*I was getting the same error as you mentioned above:*
[image]

- After researching from my end, I found that there *is **no** compatible version* of *Azure application insights* with *spring boot* `3.x.x` yet. The latest compatible version is `2.7.x`.
- The latest version of Azure Application insights is `3.0.0-beta.1` and it is compatible only with spring boot `2.x.x` version.
- Hence, it is better to use `2.x.x` versions rather than using `3.x.x`.

**References:**

Refer to [github](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Java/issues/1429) issue regarding the release of Application Insights SpringBoot Starter library.

Answer (score 0):

this is  how it worked for me (creating custom event| tarce |request |metrix telemetry)

i have added the following to the pom.xml :

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>applicationinsights-logging-logback</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
    </dependency>

   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>applicationinsights-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

then added the following (initiate the telemetryClient ):

```
    private final TelemetryClient  telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient();
```

then you need set your set your InstrumentationKey :
telemetryClient.getContext().setInstrumentationKey("PUT YOUR Instrumentation Key");  --> you can find it at your azure insight resource

then you can create :

```
    Telemetry telemetry = new EventTelemetry("Test" );
    telemetry.getContext().getOperation().setParentId("ParentId");
    telemetry.getContext().getOperation().setId(your OperationId");
    telemetryClient.track(telemetry);

    RemoteDependencyTelemetry dependencyTelemetry = new RemoteDependencyTelemetry();
    dependencyTelemetry.getContext().getOperation().setId("your OperationId");
    telemetryClient.trackDependency(dependencyTelemetry);

    RequestTelemetry requestTelemetry = new RequestTelemetry();
    requestTelemetry.getContext().getOperation().setId("your OperationId");
    telemetryClient.trackRequest(requestTelemetry);

    TraceTelemetry traceTelemetry = new TraceTelemetry();
    traceTelemetry.getContext().getOperation().setId("your OperationId");
    telemetryClient.trackTrace(traceTelemetry);
```

hope it helped .

Comment: What version of spring boot are you using? I tried applicationinsights-logging-logback together with applicationinsights-spring-boot-starter and spring boot 3.1.5